# Validation of an related null entity in a @OneToOne association in Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I have a Rule:

```
@OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private RuleParameter       parameter;
```

which can have a RuleParameter:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long                id;

private String              name;

@Column(length = 20480)
private String              value;

@OneToOne
private Rule                rule;
```

and in Controller:

```
@Autowired
UniqueRuleValidator         validator;

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    // binder.setValidator(validator);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@Valid Rule rule, BindingResult result, Model model) throws Exception {
    this.validator.validate(rule, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        log.error("Errors Saving new rule : [{}]", result.getErrorCount());
        for (ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()) {
            log.error("Error: {}", error.toString());
        }
        return "rule/form";
    } else {
        serviceConfiguration.getRuleService().save(rule);
        return "redirect:/Console/rule";
    }
}
```

and finally the validator:

```
@Component
public class UniqueRuleValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory  sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.isAssignableFrom(Rule.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        Rule rule = (Rule) obj;
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Rule.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("priority", rule.getPriority()));
        if (rule.getId() != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("id", rule.getId()));
        }
        if (criteria.list().size() > 0) {
            e.rejectValue("priority", "priority", "Priority must be unique.");
        }
    }

}
```

Since I want it to be optional, when I submit the form with the fields for RuleParameter empty I have this message:

```
ERROR: com.wit.acs.web.controller.RuleController - Error: Field error in object 'rule' on field 'parameter.value': rejected value []; codes [methodInvocation.rule.parameter.value,methodInvocation.parameter.value,methodInvocation.value,methodInvocation.java.lang.String,methodInvocation]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [rule.parameter.value,parameter.value]; arguments []; default message [parameter.value]]; default message [Property 'parameter.value' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
```

The relevant software versions:

- Java: 1.7
- Spring: 3.2.1
- hibernate-core: 3.6.10.Final
- hibernate-validator: 5.0.2.Final